# TFS check in replaces files

Tags: tfs, tfvc

tfsI get my some of my local files replaced with another version when I check in a new version of my project.
We use TFS 2010.

Here's the situation in more detail:

A colleague made significant and incomplete changes to the project leaving it nonfunctional, checked in that code and went on a two week vacation. Since these changes were not even required the obvious course of action is tho get the previous version and work from there.

The problem happens when I check in the new working version of the project: instead of just delivering files to the server I get files replaced on my machine with the server version. I never would have thought checking in  would get files from the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check in your changes, Visual Studio will always try to merge them with the latest version on the server. It must, because the version history of each file is linear, unless you manually branch files.

If the changes on the server are incompatible with your local changes, the checkin will be blocked and you will have to resolve any conflicts locally before you can check in again.

What you're seeing is expected behavior and it cannot be different due to the way TFVC works. Your colleague should not check in a version that doesn't work. In such cases he should create a shelveset (which will store the files seperately from standard history).

In your case I'd select the checkin from your colleague, select Roll back and check in the result of that. It essentially removes his changes, but they are not lost. By re-applying the rolled back changeset (roll back the roll back changeset) or by getting the specific  version with the changes he can continue working on them.